# Unable to create service SAS in Azure

Tags: azure

I want to create a service SAS for a blob storage in Azure. The parameters are:

- url= (this is the URL taken from the properties of the container)
- sv=2019-02-02
- se=2020-02-02
- sr=b
- sp=rw
- spr=https
- sig=YDiaihib7+cRay768bmfri2Z4t/kBhv8uxUGzWw5Dg4=

Signature is calculated with the following bash script:

```sh
    StringToSign="signedversion\nsignedexpiry\nsignedResource\nsignedpermissions\nsignedProtocol"
    echo -e $StringToSign| openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac secret -binary | base64
```

The value of the StringToSign variable is:

```sh
echo -e $StringToSign
signedversion
signedexpiry
signedResource
signedpermissions
signedProtocol

echo $StringToSign
signedversion\nsignedexpiry\nsignedResource\nsignedpermissions\nsignedProtocol
```

The resulting URI is:

URL/backup?sv=2019-02-02&se=2020-02-02&sr=b&sp=rw&spr=https&sig=YDiaihib7+cRay768bmfri2Z4t/kBhv8uxUGzWw5Dg4=

and the response:

```xml
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:<...> Time:<...>
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

What goes wrong here?

Thanks!

### UPDATE:

Using the

```
<BASE_URL>?restype=container&comp=list?sv=2019-02-02&sr=b&se=2020-03-01&sp=w&spr=https&sig=0AwQifXcsfqxa3Vdbzxabx2D1sMqH5NCJkp14YsDCZE=
```

now I get the following XML:

```xml
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:<request_id> Time:2020-01-09T09:13:12.0269430Z
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>
Access without signed identifier cannot have time window more than 1 hour: Start [Thu, 09 Jan 2020 09:13:12 GMT] - Expiry [Sun, 01 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT]
</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

So I guess, now I can properly generate the URL, but the configuration on the blob site is still wrong.

I set up the following access policy:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the value of “StringToSign” variable.

Comment: It is in the mentioned bash script: StringToSign="signedversion\nsignedexpiry\nsignedResource\nsignedpermissions\nsignedProtocol"

Comment: I want to see the actual value and not the placeholders.

Comment: I'm expecting to see the output in the following format: `2019-02-02\n2020-02-02\nb\nrw\https`. Are you getting this value in your `StringToSign`?

Comment: You might be right. I did try to it out. But now I get a different error in the response:
Signature did not match. String to sign used was rw 2020-02-02 /blob/<storage_account>/$root/backup https 2019-02-02 b

Comment: Please try to change the `signedresource` from `b` (blob) to `c` (container) and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help :(